# Switching between installed versions of Imagemagick

Tags: apt, package-management, versions, imagemagick

I've inherited management of an Ubuntu system running 22.04. I recently upgraded Imagemagick as part of a `apt-get upgrade` batch, but there was another version of Imagemagick already installed (I'm not sure when or how), and I can't figure out how to get the usual Imagemagick commands to run the new version and not the old.

Using the `apt show imagemagick` command identifies the current package version as `8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.3`. However, if I run `convert --version` I get `ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25` back as the version.

`which convert` points me to `/usr/bin/convert`, and when I run `dpkg -L imagemagick` I get the following output:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/copyright
/usr/share/bug/imagemagick
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/changelog.Debian.gz
```

I've spent some time trying to figure out how to "deactivate" the old version and "activate" the new, but I know it's not as simple as, say, switching between php versions. But everything I've read seems to indicate that an apt installation or update of imagemagick out to work out of the box, without any additional config. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does the command not work? See `apt-cache show imagemagick-6.q16` for more information.

Comment: On my 22.04 systemt I have a file `/usr/bin/convert` which is a link to `/etc/alternatives/convert` which is a link to `/usr/bin/convert-im6.q16` which is part of the package `imagemagick-6.q16`. I get the exact same output as you, I think there is nothing wrong with it. Since I couldn't find a package which includes the mentioned symlinks, I guess they are installed by a post-installation script. You probably shouldn't expect the exact same output by running different commands.

Comment: `apt-cache show imagemagick-6.q16` shows the current version as 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.3. So far as I know, this isn't an issue of functionality, I'm just trying to make our IT folks happy by having the latest version running on this machine.